# Expandable tree dict - making a map in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a web crawler that maps a site as it crawls. This map is written to a file so that the crawler can resume its location if an exception is thrown.

The tree starts off like this:

```
{
    "root": [{}, "example.com"]
}
```

And additional pages are nested inside the empty dict like so:

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "categoryName1": [{}, "example.com/sub1"],
            "categoryName2": [{}, "example.com/sub2"]
        }, "example.com"
    ]
}
```

I am using the following approach to scan the tree for an empty dict, which allows me to get the next url to crawl to:

```
class Crawler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = { "root": [{}, 'root.example.com'] }

    def next_url(self, recursion=None):
        tree = recursion if recursion else self.tree

        for k, v in tree.iteritems():
            _path, url = v[0], v[1]
            if not len(_path):  # is empty; latest
                return url 
            else:
                self.next_url(_path)
```

---

### Problem

Below i am creating a new branch and priming it with extracted urls. I dont know how to attach this branch onto the original `self.tree`.

```
    def add_branch(self, extractedData):
        branch = {}
        u, n = extractedData

        for url, categoryName in zip(u, n):
            branch[categoryName] = [{}, url]
```

I seem to be hitting a wall on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return both the dictionary and the url in your `Crawler.next_url` method:

```
return url, _path
```

That way, your crawling logic has access to both objects and can update the `_path` dictionary.

Comment: wouldn't `_path` in this case be an empty dict? how would this be re-attached to `self.tree`?

Comment: @AdamSalma: When did it become detached? `_path` is the dictionary in your tree.

Comment: @AdamSalma: I mean that in the sense that `_path` points to the dictionary you created earlier. Mutating `_path` changes the dictionary in your tree, since they are one and the same.

Comment: Thank you so much!!